# With speak:none deprecated, is there a way to force screenreaders not to announce :before / :after content?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I'm using the code where I add an arrow to the button

`<a href="#" class="with-arrow">Button</a>`

```
.with-arrow:after {
content: '→';
}
```

How do I specify for screenreaders that I don't want it to be read?

Just in case, I can't modify button's HTML.

Comment: As you can’t rely on what screen readers will do and as you can’t alter the HTML, and as the arrow is just a visual clue, perhaps you could use a background image - either an actual png or an embedded data uri?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control whether CSS generated content have to be read or not.
Worse, it depends on the OS / browser / screen reader. Some of them always read it, some never.

You can't assume anything, so the best is to avoid it.

Use visually hidden text instead:

```
<a href="#" class="with-arrow">Button <span class="visually-hidden">→</span></a>
```

With visually-hidden class coming from CSS frameworks like bootstrap, where it may be called sr_only.

Bonus note: CSS speech, from where `speak: none` come, isn't deprecated. In fact it never worked anywhere, as no major screen reader ever implemented support for it.

Comment: Technically, the :before and :after is part of the [accessible name spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2), step F, so if there are any screen readers that **don't** include it, that's a bug.  Now, if the `content` property is an unprintable character, then it might not be announced.

Comment: @slugolicious: Thank you for the precision. It's the case most notably for some versions of Jaws, I don't remember exactly which ones and with which browser.